# How to skip a field without entering value in c++

Tags: c++

In the below code phone number is not mandatory. How can i skip the field? If i press enter it is still waiting for my input. I want to skip the phone number field if necessary. Is that possible in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    string id, name, phone, dob;
    cout << "Enter id";
    cin >> id;
    cout << "Enter name";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter phone number";
    cin >> phone;
    cout << "Enter date of birth";
    cin >> dob;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string phone_number;
std::getline(std::cin, phone_number);
```

gets what ever was entered on that line including nothing.

Comment: when i use 2 or more getline function in a single file it skips some input.  Every time i need to add cin.ignore() before the getline function. Is that okay? Will this getline function work in gcc?

Comment: getline is a standard function, so it will work in any enviroment that properly implements the standard, so yes. See seagulls answer for ignore

Answer (score 0):

Use `getline(cin, name);` instead of `cin>>name;`. It will put a complete line to the variable. If you just press ENTER it will put an empty line.

Comment: when i use 2 or more getline function in a single file it skips some input.  Every time i need to add cin.ignore() before getline function. Is that okay? Will this getline function work in gcc?

Comment: You should put `cin.sync()` instead of `cin.ignore()` to tell the input stream that it should wait new input from user otherwise it caches some input to spead up reading and sometimes it skips some input lines. So if you use `cin.sync()` before each input everything will be ok.